# Failed To Import My Class In Yii Extensions

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I wrote a class `CronTab_Manager` to generating and managing cron jobs whith PHP. Now I want to access it everywhere in my project.
In my config file I set path of alias like below:

```
$cronTab = dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))).'/extensions/CronTab_Manager';
Yii::setPathOfAlias('cronTab',$cronTab);
```

And also import that class in this way:

```
'import'=>array(
'application.models.*',
'application.components.*',
    'cronTab.*',
),
```

My class isn't extended from other classes, and when I want to create an object of this class I receive this error:

`include(CronTab_Manager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: echo $cronTab i think its wrong path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put your class file inside models folder or components folder.

if it is as extension then

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'ext.cronTab.*',
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Set path like this:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('cronTab','ext.CronTab_Manager');
```

Comment: @HosseinSh with pleasure anytime